# Apache Storm Bolt

Tags: apache-storm

```
class MyBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
    def process(self, tup):
        data = tup.values[0].split(',')
```

I am new to Apache Storm and I see the above program but not quite understand. I wonder what `data=tup.values[0]` do. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple by defintion is an ordered list of objects. `tup.values[0]` retrieves the object from tuple **by position**. So it simply returns the first object in the tuple.